# Removi branchs (Git), mas eles "continuam" lá, como remover de vez?

Tags: git, commit

Trabalho em uma equipe de 3 pessoas e para cada ação criávamos uma branch;
com o passar do tempo a quantidade de branchs criadas se tornará grande, resolvi então eliminar algumas branchs que já não estão sendo utilizadas e que nem voltariam a ser;

Utilizei primeiramente o comando `git branch -d nome_da_branch`;

Ainda não tendo o objetivo alcançado, utilizei de outro comando: `git push origin --delete nome_da_branch`;

A ideia era remover a branch da minha maquina e da rede de todo o pessoal;

Algumas branchs sumiram na minha maquina local porém não da maquina do pessoal que trabalha comigo; existem branchs que aparecem pra mim com a opção de publicar ("Publish Branch");

Gostaria de um auxilio quanto a fazer remoção das branchs;
Já utilizei o comando `git clean -[]` [n, i, f] conforme a documentação do Git porém nada ainda aconteceu;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para deletar a branch remota:

```
git push nome_do_origin nome_da_branch --delete
```

Para deletar a branch local:

```
git branch -D nome_da_branch
```

Comment: As branchs continuam aparecendo nas demais maquinas ligadas a Release e a Master e com a opção de "Publish".

Comment: As referências continuará nos demais. Para solucionar, tentem o comando: git remote prune

Comment: Infelizmente as branchs continuam aparecendo no VSCode.
Mas agradeço a todos pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Para deletar uma *branch* remota:

```
git push origin :nome_da_branch
```

Para remover a referência da *branch* dos demais desenvolvedores cada um terá que digitar o comando:

```
git fetch -pt
```

A opção `-pt` do comando [`fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) é a junção das opções [`-p`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt--p) e [`-t`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt--t).

A remoção local deverá ocorrer em cada máquina:

```
git branch -D <minha_branch>
```

Answer (score -1):

opto mais pelo trabalho manual.

1. apago a branch com: `git branch -D nome_da_branch`
2. apago o projeto da maquina: `rm -r nome_do_repositorio`
3. e faço um clone novamente: `git clone url_repositorio`

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Se vc vai apagar o repositório da sua máquina e depois clonar de novo, o passo 1 é desnecessário. Além disso, a pergunta também pede para remover do repositório remoto e das outras pessoas que também clonaram, então o procedimento completo seria o que está [nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/223679/112052)